# Can i read value from sensors then add it to JSON string for RF24l01 network

Tags: c, json, arduino

i read a few example and the value is string or number like this

```
json[] =
      "{\"sensor\":\"gps\",\"time\":1351824120,\"data\":[48.756080,2.302038]}";
```

For example i have 2 values:

```
pack0.humidity = dht.readHumidity();
pack0.temperature = dht.readTemperature();
```

Can i read those temp and humid and add it to json in loop()
like this

```
  json[] =
          "{\"Temperature\": /*temp here*/,
           \"Humidity\":/*humid here*/}";
```

Could anyone give me example for my project. thanks a lot.
My current code for rf24

```
struct package0
  {
    float temperature = 0;
    float humidity = 0;
    int soil = 0;
  };
  typedef struct package0 Package0;
  Package0 pack0;
void loop()
{
  delay(2000);
  pack0.humidity = dht.readHumidity();
  pack0.temperature = dht.readTemperature();
  pack0.soil = map(analogRead(SOILPIN), 0, 4096, 100, 0);//convert to percentage
  if (isnan(pack0.humidity) || isnan(pack0.temperature))
  {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return;
  }
  RF24NetworkHeader header(master00);
  bool ok = network.write(header, &pack0, sizeof(pack0));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using [ArduinoJson](https://arduinojson.org/), which will do the JSON encoding for you. The advantage of this library is that it makes it easy to modify your data schema at a later time.

Or you can do it yourself by simply using `snprintf`:

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 48; // Choose a suitable number here
char json[BUFFER_SIZE];
snprintf(json, BUFFER_SIZE, "{\"Temperature\":%f,\"Humidity\":%f}", pack0.humidity, pack0.temperature);
```

`json` will then contain your JSON data. Using `snprintf` ensures that the write will not overflow.

Comment: For my project, i want to store data in json then i will send json this_node to other_node using RF24l01. i'm not experienced with JSON before, sorry.
can JSON do like this:

`const int BUFFER_SIZE = 48; // Choose a suitable number here`

`char json[BUFFER_SIZE] = "{\"Temperature\":%f,\"Humidity\":%f}", pack0.humidity, pack0.temperature); `